# How does Visual Studio Auto Created Authentication access my Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

VS 2015, ASP.Net 4.5.2 Templates, Azure hosting

I created a MVC project and allowed VS to script in the needed database objects to handle Authentication. I pointed it to an existing SQL Server database on Azure. All went great and I see the changes to my DB, so far all I find is a few added tables.

My question is how does my new website access those authentication tables? I didn't notice any new stored procedures. I haven't been able to find where in my project it hits the DB?

Thanks!

Comment: ASP.Net Identity uses Entity Framework Code First. It doesn't use Store Procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the tutorials at https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-data. This question is easily answered, once you know how Entity Framework works.

Long and short, your entity classes represent tables in your database. Most likely you'll have just one in your actual project, `ApplicationUser`, but the others live in the ASP.NET Identity namespace.

Also in your project, you'll find an `ApplicationDbContext`, which inherits from `IdentityDbContext`. This is your "unit of work" and corresponds to the database these entities' tables exist in.

Finally, the `UserManager` class interacts with your context under the hood. You can also directly interact with the context; you don't necessarily need `UserManager` for a lot of things. It's simply a utility class Identity provides that takes care of a lot of the cruft.